# Rating of Woocommerce does not work on custom WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been "googling" about this and I can not find a solution. I have done exactly what the Woocommerce documentation explains and in other forums where the solutions refer to the same Woocommerce source, but it still does not work.

I have woocommerce's support in my theme and enabled review in woocommerce setting [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWYEz.png)

Here is my code:

```
$woo = apply_filters( 't_em_filter_woocommerce', array(
    'thumbnail_image_width' => 150,
    'single_image_width'    => 300,
    'product_grid'          => array(
        'default_rows'      => 3,
        'min_rows'          => 2,
        'max_rows'          => 8,
        'default_columns'   => 4,
        'min_columns'       => 5,
        'max_columns'       => 5,
    ),
) );
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce', $woo );
```

Simply the "stars" to mark the Rating do not appear.

Thank everyone

Comment: You should include the code in your question, as links can change or be removed.

Comment: have you tried 
$product = wc_get_product( $id );
echo wc_get_rating_html( $product->get_average_rating() );
in your template

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain correctly. Stars appear in product review, what does not appear is the option to mark the stars in comments review. I'm working with an imported database, so some products are already rated, in the old site all goes fine, but in the new one Im having this issue. I'm not English speaking, so forgive my bad grammar